# Showing webview in AndEngine GLES 2 while the game is running on Android

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am working on a game while the game is running I need to show a webview with some instructions from web is that possible?

These instructions will be shown again and again and are dynamic as they are coming from a server.

Can you please help me with that? I cannot use LayoutBaseGameActivity as I don't want to show them always.

I want to pause the game and show a webview which will be clickable. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your game activity to show WebView and call openWebViewURL or openWebViewHTML when you need

```java
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);

    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams webViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100,
                    Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);

    webView = new WebView(this);

    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(webView, webViewLayoutParams);
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

    webView.setVisibility(webView.INVISIBLE);

}

private void openWebViewURL(String url) {

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

private void openWebViewHTML(String html) {

    webView.loadData(html,"text/html", "en_US");

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't know this is possible, very useful!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you Start a new Activity to show the webpage.
the user can close the activity when they finish. And there is nothing change in the game. :D
Hopte it can help you :D

Comment: No I don't to open it in a new activity I want to show it on Game Screen